# Android - Problems saving and loading Objects after App has been closed

Tags: java, android, save

I'm trying to save the gamestate of my App so that it can be reload after restarting the App. The Object I'm trying to save is quite complex and holds a lot of data. I've been looking for different solutions and tried a lot.

The closest I've got is that the App is able to save and load the data during runtime.
And when closing and restarting the App it sometimes succeeds loading the data as well, but just in really rare moments.

Does anybody has an idea what the problem might be?

The `Object` I'm trying to save looks like the following (the unimportant functions I left out):

```
public class SCSpieldaten  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //Aktuelles Spiel
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static Random rand = new Random();
    public static int EinTabletBedienung        = 1;
    public static int KartePortLand             = 0;
    public static int AktuelleRunde             = 0;
    public static int AktiverSpieler            = 0;
    public static int AktivesDorf               = 0;
    public static int AktuellerBauplatz         = 1;
    public static int AktuellStaerksterMacht[]  = {KEINEANGABE,KEINEANGABE,KEINEANGABE};
    public static int SelektiertePositionX      = 0;
    public static int SelektiertePositionY      = 0;
    public static int AktuellesFeld             = 1;
    public static int AktuellesGebaeude         = 1;
    public static int AktuellesGebiet           = 0;
    public static int AktuelleAnzahlUnit[]      = {0,0,0};
    public static int AktuellerEinheitentyp[]   = {KEINEANGABE,KEINEANGABE,KEINEANGABE};
    public static int AktuellerBericht          = 0;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> SpinnerBerichtNr           = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static ArrayList<ArrayAdapter<String>> ArrayAdapter  = new ArrayList<ArrayAdapter<String>>();
    public static ArrayList<CBericht> CB_AktuellerBericht       = new ArrayList<CBericht>();
    public static CKosten AktuelleKosten                        = new CKosten(0,0,0,0,0);
    public static CGebaeude TempGebaeude                        = new CGebaeude();
    public static ArrayList<CSpieler> CS_Spieler                = new ArrayList<CSpieler>();
    public static ArrayList<CNeutralesLager> CN_NeutralesLager  = new ArrayList<CNeutralesLager>();
    public static ArrayList<CWegzoll> CW_Wegzoll                = new ArrayList<CWegzoll>();
    public static CDorf CD_Handelsstadt                         = new CDorf(GEBIETNEUTRAL);
    public static CDorf CD_Festung                              = new CDorf(GEBIETNEUTRAL);
    public static CDorf CD_Forschungszentrum                    = new CDorf(GEBIETNEUTRAL);
    public static CUnterstuetzung CU_FestungVerteidigung        = new CUnterstuetzung();
    public static CUnterstuetzung CU_FestungStartArmee          = new CUnterstuetzung();
    public static Integer[][] SpielerStatistic                  = new Integer[6][100];  


public void save(Context c) throws IOException
{
    FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput("test0.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    os.writeObject(this);
    os.close();
}

public SCSpieldaten load(Context c) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    FileInputStream fis = c.openFileInput("test0.txt");
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    SCSpieldaten simpleClass = (SCSpieldaten) is.readObject();
    is.close();
    return simpleClass;
}
```

I Also tried using ObjectOutputStream but when restarting the app it seems like the file got deleatet

```
public boolean saveObject(SCSpieldaten obj) {
    File suspend_f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.txt");
    if(!suspend_f.exists())
    {
        try {
            suspend_f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }               

    FileOutputStream   fos  = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos  = null;
    boolean            keep = true;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(suspend_f);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(obj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        keep = false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (oos != null)   oos.close();
            if (fos != null)   fos.close();
            if (keep == false) suspend_f.delete();
    } catch (Exception e) { /* do nothing */ }
    }

    return keep;
}

public SCSpieldaten getObject(Context c) {
    File suspend_f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.txt");

    SCSpieldaten simpleClass= null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream is = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(suspend_f);
        is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        simpleClass = (SCSpieldaten) is.readObject();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        String val= e.getMessage();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null)   fis.close();
            if (is != null)   is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }

    return simpleClass;  
}
```

Comment: Lots of Static variable !!!, Think the load on your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

why cant you use `AsyncTask` http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html for this

Answer (score 0):

I actually just went over this in class. Android has a built in auto save function that should  save your data on exit... Question: How are you closing / exiting the app ? I asked this because i believe the data is stored in your RAM if your not using a sqlLIte stored procedure... If this is the case... the way you exit your app DOES matter and may be deleting your data... You could try and save all data when the user loses focus

```
if blah.lostfocus
yourData .store value
```

You should probably use a persistent stored method in case of app crash as you mentioned.

Check this link to show you how - [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: I'm closing it via task manager, because the data should also be able to be reloaded after a crash of the app.

Comment: Thats why your losing your data. Your going to need a persistent storage method.

Comment: I also tried ObjectOutputStream. But I've had the same Problem. But shouldn't that be a persistent storage method.

Comment: It is.. But you would have to write to a file and then on Load inputStream

Comment: I edit my question. there you can see what I did.
And again it works fine during runtime. but when I'm restarting the app the data is gone